# "CSRF verification failed. CSRF token missing or incorrect." Django

Tags: python, django, token, csrf, verification

I am trying to create a Django app based on the [Django Classifieds App](https://github.com/saebyn/django-classifieds), but am getting an error when trying to submit the form: `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Reason given for failure: CSRF token missing or incorrect.`

I do have a `{% csrf_token %}` in the form:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url classifieds.views.create.checkout ad.pk %}">
 {% csrf_token %}
  <table>
   {{ form }}
     <tr>
     <th><label>Total:</label></th>
     <td><div id="total">Choose options above</div></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I also am using `from django.template import RequestContext`

I also have included `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',` in the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in my settings.py

What else could I be missing to properly submit the form?

The function looks like:

```
def checkout(request, adId):
   ad = get_object_or_404(Ad, pk=adId)
   if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CheckoutForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

 ...

  payment.save()

  if django_settings.DEBUG:
    paypal_form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_values).sandbox()
  else:
    paypal_form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_values).render()

  return render_to_response('classifieds/paypal.html', {'form': paypal_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
  form = CheckoutForm()

return render_to_response('classifieds/checkout.html', {'ad': ad, 'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Do you have csrf middleware and context processor?

Comment: Chech if you have required middleware/decorator and other things in place... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works

Comment: Yes, I do have 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in my settings.py. Anything else that I could be missing? Thank you

Comment: clean up browser cache or use another browser to try

Comment: Did you use correct `RequestContext`, i am not sure if the problem is that, but you may check it too. Step 3 of this guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it

Comment: Thank you for the link @FallenAngel. I was missing `from django.core.context_processors import csrf` in my views. If you would like to post that as the answer I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you use correct `RequestContext`, i am not sure if the problem is that, but you may check it too. Step 3 of [how to use it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it)

> - In the corresponding view functions, ensure that the 'django.core.context_processors.csrf' context processor is being used. Usually, this can be done in one of two ways:
>
>   1. Use RequestContext, which always uses 'django.core.context_processors.csrf' (no matter what your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting). If you are using generic views or contrib apps, you are covered already, since these apps use RequestContext throughout

Comment: [how to use it](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it) link is no longer valid. This is [valid link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/)